# How to override an HTMLElement native method globally?

Tags: javascript, function, overriding, native

I am trying to wrap a function that is implemented for all SVGElements called `getScreenCTM`.

My goal is that all invocations of this method for all svg elements will invoke my wrapper function that will print something and then delegate to the original, native implementation.

Here is what I tried:

`<svg id="a"></svg>`

and

```
window.nativeGetScreenCTM = SVGElement.prototype.getScreenCTM;

SVGElement.prototype.getScreenCTM = function() {
  var matrix = window.nativeGetScreenCTM();
  console.log('printing something:');
  return matrix;
};

var svgElem = document.getElementById('a');

svgElem.getScreenCTM();
```

but when the last line is executed, nothing is printed. The original `getScreenCTM` is invoked instead of my wrapper implementation.

You can play with it here: https://jsfiddle.net/zwxr2c9k/1/

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably extending the wrong element, looks like you have a `SVGGraphicsElement`

```js
window.nativeGetScreenCTM = SVGGraphicsElement.prototype.getScreenCTM;

SVGGraphicsElement.prototype.getScreenCTM = function() {
  var matrix = window.nativeGetScreenCTM.apply(this, arguments);
  console.log('printing something:');
  return matrix;
};

var svgElem = document.getElementById('a');

svgElem.getScreenCTM();
```

```html
<svg id="a"></svg>
```

Also note that you can't just call `window.nativeGetScreenCTM`, as it requires the `this` value to be an actual SVG element.
You can however call it with `apply` or `call`